# Can a topological manifold have different tangent bundles?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

We know that the tangent bundles of the sphere arising from different smooth structures are equivalent as vector bundles. Is it right in general? I want to know the relationship between the set of smooth structures and these tangent bundles.

Comment: You might want to look up the Novikov conjecture.

Comment: It seems like a negative answer to the (open) Novikov conjecture would give an example here where the tangent bundles are different. That doesn't directly imply that the original question is open, however.

Comment: Thanks Mckay  for editing them to make them more aware and Belegradek for  giving an enlightening answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is answered in [Crowley, Diarmuid J.; Zvengrowski, Peter D, On the non-invariance of span and immersion co-dimension for manifolds, Arch. Math. (Brno) 44 (2008), no. 5, 353–365], see [here](http://www.dcrowley.net/Span.pdf).

Specifically, in each dimension $>8$ there is a closed PL manifold admitting two smooth structures whose tangent bundles are non-isomorphic. One tangent bundle is trivial and the other one has nonzero second Pontryagin class. See remark 1.3.

Such examples do not exist in dimensions $\le 8$ by Corollary 2.6.

In dimensions $\ge 18$ this was known since 1969 and due to Roitberg in
[On the PL noninvariance of the span of a smooth manifold,  Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 20, No. 2 (Feb., 1969), pp. 575-579].

Comment: I think the first example was actually given by Milnor in his 1963 paper [*Microbundles, Part I*](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/micro001.pdf), namely Theorem 9.2.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: True, even though Milnor's example is for tangent bundles of open manifolds.